Ubuntu 24.4 lts login broken after a new install
I just installed the latest Ubuntu lts twice to find out that password field doesn't function properly when trying to log in. It doesn't say that my password is wrong, but instead told that my password didn't work and asked to try again. After installing again and making sure that no typos were present, I tried the alternate ways to fix this. I went to grub and  made the password field rewritable and then rewrote it in root terminal. It said that password was set successfully. However, after getting back to login screen, the same problem persists. Is there still some way to get this installation working? If the problem is with Wayland, can I remove it and use Xorg only?

Check that your keyboard matches your locale.

I checked that the password characters were as intended by using the eye icon. Also, while installing I selected the layout I always use.
